# Static and Sticky fixed header transition misfunction

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a sticky header based on scroll even but there are two problems:

1. When scrolling up and down, there is jump at background. (I hope you
   understand what I mean)
2. Sometimes both header divs appear together.

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks in advance

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ezBXc/)

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#header, #page, #footer
{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
#header
{
    background: #CCCCCC;
}
#default
{
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    background: #64D989;
}
#sticky
{
    display: none;
    height: 50px;
    background: #D9D164;
}
#footer
{
    background: #EEEEEE;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(window).bind("scroll", function(e)
    {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100)
        { 
            $("#header").css('position', 'fixed');
            $("#default").css('display', 'none');
            $("#sticky").css('display', 'block');
        }
        else
        {
            $("#header").css('position', 'relative');
            $("#sticky").css('display', 'none');
            $("#default").css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="default">I AM DEFAULT HEADER</div>
    <div id="sticky">I APPEAR IF SCROLL POSITION > 100px</div>
</div>

<div id="page">
        START<br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        END
</div>

<div id="footer">I AM PAGE FOOTER</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first problem: part of the flash you are seeing is due to the fact that the `sticky` header won't appear until the scroll position is > 100. Since the `default` header has a height of 100px, when the scroll position is exatly 100px neither header is showing.

You can fix this by changing `if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100)` to `if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 100)`.

For the second issue of both divs showing at the same time, you'll need to [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) the current animation before hiding the div. See below:

**EDIT** I've updated to address performance concerns using the techniques John Resig posted here: http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/ Note that this will introduce a 250ms delay, so there will be a slight delay when transitioning from the default header to the sticky header.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ezBXc/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sticky = $('#sticky'),
        defaultHeader = $('#default'),
        header = $('#header')
        defaultShowing = true,
        didScroll = false;

    $(window).on("scroll", function (e) {
        didScroll = true;
    });

    window.setInterval(function () {
        if(didScroll) {
            didScroll = false;
            var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();

            if (defaultShowing && scrollTop >= 100) {
                defaultShowing = false;
                header.css('position', 'fixed');
                defaultHeader.stop().hide();
                sticky.fadeIn(1000);
            } else if (!defaultShowing && scrollTop < 100) {
                defaultShowing = true;
                header.css('position', 'relative');
                sticky.stop().hide();
                defaultHeader.fadeIn(1000);
            }
        }
    }, 250);
});
```

Comment: It didn't fix second problem. scroll down fast and scroll up fast again to see both dives together.

Comment: As @Mooseman mentioned, it plays up in different browsers like FF. Is there any other way of implementing what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Thanks for that. Why do you think our example doesn't behave like this site? http://eplus-gruppe.de/

Comment: It is not my site. I want my example to work like that. Currently it plays up in transition. Also I removed fadeIn() and put normal css in.

Comment: Found the solution. I should have used `fixed` not `relative`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by background, as all backgrounds in the CSS you show are solid.

Binding an event to `scroll` with jQuery's `.on()` can get slow on some browsers. Meaning that it won't fire as often as it should, delaying any function bound the the scroll event. Also, since you're taking `1000ms` to fade in the div, that will make the delay seem longer.

Comment: As you mentioned, it plays up in different browsers like FF. Is there any other way of implementing what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Binding an event is the best way, but storing variables for the selectors instead of using the selectors every time will help performance.