# Scroll to top JavaScript in HTML Website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement the scroll to top feature in my website: www.arrow-tvseries.com.

The "button" is seen on the website however it does not work properly, because when clicked its not scrolling to the top of the page. More over I would like that the "Scroll to top button" is visible when scrolled down, say half the page.

Here is the javascript code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"         type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() != 200) {
        $('#backtotop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#backtotop').fadeOut();
    }
});

$('#backtotop').click(function() {
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},800);
});
});
</script>
```

HTML Code (Head Tag):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <title>Arrow-TvSeries - Home</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <!--back to top links-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="back_to_top.css">
        <script src="/scripts/back_to_top.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--end of back to top links-->

    <meta property="fb:admins" content="{793705343}"/>
    <!--Google Analytics-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-40124321-1', 'arrow-tvseries.com');
      ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Arrow Tv Show">
    <meta name="keywords" content="arrow, tv show, amel, stephen amell, katie cassidy, oliver, oliver queen, queen">
    <meta name="author" content="Ståle Refsnes">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!--IPAD setting-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = 730, initial-scale=0.70, minimum-scale = 0.5,  maximum-scale = 1.25"/>
</head>
```

CSS Code:

```
#backtotop {
cursor : pointer;
/*display : none;*/
margin : 0px 0px 0px 370px;
position : fixed;
bottom : 10px;
font-size : 90%;
padding : 10px;
width : 100px;
text-align : center;
background-color : #000;
border-radius : 8px;
-webkit-border-radius : 8px;
-moz-border-radius : 8px;
filter: alpha(opacity=60);
-khtml-opacity : 0.6;
-moz-opacity : 0.6;
opacity : 0.6;
color : #FFF;
font-size : 14px;
z-index : 10000;
font-family: arial;
}

#backtotop:hover {
filter : alpha(opacity=90);
-khtml-opacity : 0.9;
-moz-opacity : 0.9;
opacity : 0.9;
}
```

Please feel free and let me know if you require further code or information.

Thanks

Comment: The answer to this question may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043145/static-and-sticky-fixed-header-transition-misfunction/17043288#17043288

Comment: Also, you have a few syntax errors on your site, check the `Console` tab in `Firebug (Firefox)` or Google Chrome's `Developer Tools` - F12

Comment: Just copy and pasted everything into the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hEhnt/. The back to top button works there, but I made no changes to your code.

Comment: I posted a solution that allows you to keep your original code (because your code works!). There are other (possibly better?) ways to do what you want, but that was not your question.

Comment: The website is live at the moment, when I try it there it does not work... www.arrow-tvseries.com

I will check out the solutions given in your comments and see what might be the problem, will also fix the syntax errors present im my code.

I am a mac user and I'm using Safari and Chrome as browsers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it is not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            input.pos_fixed
            {
                position:fixed;
                top:30px;
                right:5px;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            function scrollWindow()
            {
                window.scrollTo(0,0);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <br>
            <input class="pos_fixed" type="button" onclick="scrollWindow()" value="Scroll" />
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing with below code:

```
$("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```

Try this. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZreKK/1/)**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    // if you have scrolled down more than 200px
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $('#backtotop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#backtotop').fadeOut();
    }
});



$('#backtotop').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},800);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your javascript file is actually written in HTML.

In your HTML `head` section, you should have:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/back_to_top.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then your `back_to_top.js` should contain **only** the following:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() != 200) {
            $('#backtotop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#backtotop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('#backtotop').click(function() {
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},800);
    });
});
```