# Implementing "scroll to top" button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here on my website is has a "back to top" feature:

https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/

Scroll th epage down and then you will see it. Now, this feature was implemented as part of the theme I am using in Wordpress.

I want to use this same feature on another page on another site for learning purposes. I tried to locate all the bits I needed and I have got this far:

http://trucklesoft.co.uk/test/backtotop.php#

The problems I am having are:

- The size of the box is not the same
- The chevron is not aligned in the same way
- Nothing happens when I click the chevron
- The box is always visible

What steps am I missing here?

## Update

based on the comments I have added a couple of `script` lines. I now have this in my `head` section:

```
<head>
<link href="/test/fa/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!--load all styles -->
<script defer src="/test/fa/js/all.js"></script> <!--load all styles -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='test/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='test/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var cnArgs = {"ajaxurl":"https:\/\/www.publictalksoftware.co.uk\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","hideEffect":"fade","onScroll":"no","onScrollOffset":"100","cookieName":"cookie_notice_accepted","cookieValue":"true","cookieTime":"2592000","cookiePath":"\/","cookieDomain":"","redirection":"","cache":"","refuse":"no","revoke_cookies":"0","revoke_cookies_opt":"automatic","secure":"1"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#sv-totop {
    position: fixed;
    right: 40px;
    bottom: 65px;
    display: none;
    outline: none;
    background: #d35438 !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 30px 30px -30px #7F7F7F, inset 0 -30px 30px -30px #7F7F7F;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 30px 30px -30px #7F7F7F, inset 0 -30px 30px -30px #7F7F7F;
    box-shadow: inset 0 30px 30px -30px #606060, inset 0 -30px 30px -30px #606060;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #E7D8A3 !important;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
    transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
    font-family: 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
    z-index: 99999999;
}
#sv-totop:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var colomatduration = 'fast';
    var colomatslideEffect = 'slideFade';
    var colomatpauseInit = '';
    var colomattouchstart = '';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 500 )
                $("#sv-totop").fadeIn();
            else
                $("#sv-totop").fadeOut();
        });

        $("#sv-totop").click(function () {
            $("body,html").animate({ scrollTop: 0 },1000 );
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    });  
</script>
</head>
```

It has improved a bit. BUt now it jumps and does not scroll. I don't understand why my javascript is not being called.

Comment: Please read [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and create a [mcve] demonstrating your issue

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199724/scroll-to-top-javascript-in-html-website?rq=1

Comment: Looks like the jQuery file is being referenced incorrectly. It's looking in the location: http://trucklesoft.co.uk/test/test/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4. It cannot be found preventing the custom jQuery script from working

Comment: @Jetchy Thanks. I forgot the path was relative to the file location for testing.  I adjusted the paths and cleared cache but it still only jumps.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Still not found. You need to double check where you are hosting the jQuery file. If that's not straightforward - you could use the jQuery CDN just to check the scrolling animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look of this guide, I think it could be quite helpful [How TO - Scroll Back To Top Button](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp)

```js
  // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
    }
}
  
  $('#myBtn').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 700);
    });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>

<div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:30px">Scroll Down</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgrey;padding:30px 30px 2500px">This example demonstrates how to create a "scroll to top" button that becomes visible when the user starts to scroll the page.</div>
```

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: BAsed on the link in the comments to my question I have added two `script` lines and now it jumps to the top. But, it does not "scroll" to the top.

Comment: oh I see, ok let me provide you something else

Comment: @AndrewTruckle now it should "scroll" to the top

Comment: Thanks. I can see your test working. But I can't replicate: http://trucklesoft.co.uk/test/backtotop4.html

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, please try placing the script just before the </body> closing tag

Comment: That works! http://trucklesoft.co.uk/test/backtotop5.html Now I just have to make the anchor look and behave like my original. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173813/discussion-between-matt-and-andrew-truckle).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a small bit of JS to work out how far you need to move and then use animation frames to scroll.

I've adapted and simplified this [project](https://pawelgrzybek.com/page-scroll-in-vanilla-javascript/)

The `querySelectorAll` bit at the bottom specifically looks for anchors that are internal and turns them into scroll buttons.

```js
function scrollIt(destination, duration = 350) {
  const start = window.pageYOffset;
  const startTime = 'now' in window.performance ? performance.now() : new Date().getTime();
  const body = document.body;
  const dele = document.documentElement;

  const dHeight = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, dele.clientHeight, dele.scrollHeight, dele.offsetHeight);
  const wHeight = window.innerHeight || dele.clientHeight || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
  const dOffset = typeof destination === 'number' ? destination : destination.offsetTop;
  const dOffsetScroll = Math.round(dHeight - dOffset < wHeight ? dHeight - wHeight : dOffset);

  if ('requestAnimationFrame' in window === false) {
    window.scroll(0, dOffsetScroll);
    return;
  }

  function scroll() {
    const now = 'now' in window.performance ? performance.now() : new Date().getTime();
    const time = Math.min(1, ((now - startTime) / duration));
    const timeFunction = time;
    window.scroll(0, Math.ceil((timeFunction * (dOffsetScroll - start)) + start));

    window.pageYOffset === dOffsetScroll || requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
  }

  scroll();
}

document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const href = e.target.getAttribute('href');
    if (href.match(/^#/)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (href.match(/^#$/)) {
        scrollIt(0);
      } else {
        scrollIt(document.querySelector(href));
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<div>
  test <a href="#test">to bottom</a>
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div id="test">
  test <a href="#">to top</a>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

I hope you find this helpful.